# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Update element content/html of the form using Partial action and jQuery ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have Partial `A1` inside Partial `A`.

I need to render my Partial view `A1` on button `A1B` click.

For that i have an partial view action with parameter type of model of Partial view `A` (because there is some dependencies on `A`)

```
public PartialViewResult A1Partial(A model)
{
    //Getting my deserialized model here successfully

    //doing changes in the model collections

    return PartialView("A1Partial", model);
}
```

I have onclick function to call my `A1Partial` partial action:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#A1B").click(function () {

        dataString = $("#myForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/A1Partial",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) { 
                            //not working here

                            $("#myDiv").html("");
                $("#myDiv").html(data); 
            }

        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

My call from jQuery ajax working correctly and dataString getting deserialized in controller without any issues.

But i am didn't get anything in `$("#myDiv").append(data);` looks like the html didn't came through.

What changes i need to made to make it work?

Comment: Have you checked the request was successful using something like fiddler? i.e. it returns 200 and you can see this response being sent to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicate that you expect a JSON response type:

```
dataType: "json"
```

And yet you try to use it as if it was HTML:

```
$('#myDiv').append(data);
```

So remove this `dataType: 'json'` from the AJAX request and in the success callback the data variable will represent the HTML returned by the `A1Partial`.

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, I still see `dataType: "json"` in your updated question. So what happens when you remove it?

Comment: I think you've missed Darin's point here, you need to change dataType to html, and your original code should work (with the append call)

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, you don't need to specify this. jQuery will use the server Content-Type HTTP response header to guess the content. But it is not wrong to set `dataType: 'html'` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the partial view on the server and then send the HTML result via Json like this:

```
public static class Renders
{
    public static string RenderPartialView(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public JsonResult A1Partial(A model)
{
    //Getting my deserialized model here successfully

    //doing changes in the model collections

    return Json(new
    {
        Html = this.RenderPartialView("A1Partial", model)
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in the JQuery code:

```
$("#myDiv").html(data.Html);
```

Comment: Why not like just that  'return PartialView("A1Partial", model);' what is the purpose of having extension method 'RenderPartialView'?

Comment: In a real app things can go wrong, for example the code inside A1Partial can raise a db exception... I can notice the user by adding a new parameter to my JsonResult that is not part of the partial view.